# Get the source of images from table cell

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get to the `img.src` of these table cells, but am going wrong somewhere.

```
var cell = newTable.rows.cells;
var content = newTable.getElementsByTagName('img');
var nodeArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < content.length; ++i)
{
    nodeArray[i] = content[i];
}

var listThem = $(this).attr('src');
console.log(listThem);
```

Comment: Ermm... what's the point of going through `content` and setting all `nodeArray[i]` to `content[i]` when you can just set it to `content` in the first place...? E.g., `var nodeArray = content;` Also, with what you're showing us, we really can't help you at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
var content = newTable.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i += 1) {
    var source = content[i]['src'];
    //do something
}
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of dom elements.
To access the "src" attribute of a dom element, you can do this : `element.src` or `element['src']`;

`source` will contain the image source.

Comment: Cheers Libert, as it turned out I was nearly there. I was trying .src. I guess when you're learning it's the little things that trip us up, but we all have to start somewhere. Thanks.